# Moving to the next cell in Excel after searching using C#

Tags: c#, excel

Eg.
Searching for value "A" which is in A1.
And moving to the next cell B1 and displaying it.

How would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Search for Text in Worksheet Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[Reading Excel From C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380)

[Retrieving Excel 2007 Cell Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332058.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CallCellReader(ArrayList myArray, int Count, int noRec)
{
    try
    {
        char c = 'A';
        for (int l = 1; l <= Count; l++)
        {
            int k = 2;
            for (int i = 1; i <= noRec; i++)
            {
                m_objRange = m_objSheet.get_Range(c.ToString() + k.ToString(), c.ToString() + k.ToString());
                myArray.Add(m_objRange.Cells.Value2.ToString());
                k++;
            }
            c++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Log.Add("Error in Reading Excel file " +exc);
        LogFlag = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a explanation of atleast 1 line.